# Anisotropic lighting in OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0. Black artifacts

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, artifacts, opengl-es-3.0

I am trying to implement anisotropic lighting.
Vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es
uniform mat4 u_mvMatrix; 
uniform mat4 u_vMatrix;

in vec4 a_position; 
in vec3 a_normal; 
...
out lowp float v_DiffuseIntensity;
out lowp float v_SpecularIntensity;

const vec3 lightPosition = vec3(-1.0, 0.0, 5.0);
const lowp vec3 grainDirection = vec3(15.0, 2.8, -1.0);
const vec3 eye_positiion = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

void main() {
    // transform normal orientation into eye space
    vec3 modelViewNormal = mat3(u_mvMatrix) * a_normal;
    vec3 modelViewVertex = vec3(u_mvMatrix * a_position);
    vec3 lightVector = normalize(lightPosition - modelViewVertex);
    lightVector = mat3(u_vMatrix) * lightVector;

    vec3 normalGrain = cross(modelViewNormal, grainDirection);
    vec3 tangent = normalize(cross(normalGrain, modelViewNormal));
    float LdotT = dot(tangent, normalize(lightVector));
    float VdotT = dot(tangent, normalize(mat3(u_mvMatrix) * eye_position));
    float NdotL = sqrt(1.0 - pow(LdotT, 2.0));
    float VdotR = NdotL * sqrt(1.0 - pow(VdotT, 2.0)) - VdotT * LdotT;
    v_DiffuseIntensity = max(NdotL * 0.4 + 0.6, 0.0);
    v_SpecularIntensity = max(pow(VdotR, 2.0) * 0.9, 0.0);
    ...
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
...
in lowp float v_DiffuseIntensity;
in lowp float v_SpecularIntensity;

const lowp vec3 default_color = vec3(0.1, 0.7, 0.9);

void main() {
    ...
    lowp vec3 resultColor = (default_color * v_DiffuseIntensity) 
        + v_SpecularIntensity;
    outColor = vec4(resultColor, 1.0);
}
```

Overall, the lighting works well on different devices. But an artifact appears on the SAMSUNG tablet, as shown in the figure:

[image]

It seems that the darkest place is becoming completely black. Can anyone please suggest why this is happening? Thanks for any answer/comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of expressions that risk undefined behaviour:

```
sqrt(1.0 - pow(LdotT, 2.0))
sqrt(1.0 - pow(VdotT, 2.0))
```

The `pow` function is undefined if x is negative. I suspect you're getting away with this because y is 2.0 so they're probably optimised to just be x * x.

The `sqrt` function is undefined if x is negative. Mathematically it never should be since the magnitude of the dot product of two normalized vectors should never be more than 1, but computations always have error. I think this is causing your rendering artifacts.

I'd change those two expressions to:

```
sqrt(max(0.0, 1.0 - pow(max(0.0, LdotT), 2.0)))
sqrt(max(0.0, 1.0 - pow(max(0.0, VdotT), 2.0)))
```

The code looks a lot uglier, but it's safer and `max(0.0, x)` is a pretty cheap operation.

Edit: Just noticed `pow(VdotR, 2.0)`, I'd change that too.

Comment: Changing sqrt-expressions solved the problem. Artifacts completely disappeared. Thank You very much!